# hreflang for China Taiwan zh-Hans zh-Hant or zh-cn zh-tw

Tags: seo, cjk, hreflang

Hello thanks for any input, ok the Hreflang, should I use the zh-Hans zh-Hant or zh-cn zh-tw
as seen below, cheers

```
<a href="https://www.websitename*^%$.com/zh-hans/index.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-Hans">简体中文 (Chinese Simplified)</a>
<a href="https://www.websitename*^%$.com/zh-hant/index.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-Hant">繁體中文 (Chinese Traditional)</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://www.websitename*^%$.com/zh-hans/index.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-cn">简体中文 (Chinese Simplified)</a>
<a href="https://www.websitename*^%$.com/zh-hant/index.php" rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-tw">繁體中文 (Chinese Traditional)</a>
```